# Vue.js select all input fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to select all input fields when I click the `Select all names` button but that's not working?

I've made a example:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        names: [ 
            { "name": "one" },
            { "name": "two" },
            { "name": "three" }
        ]
    },
    created() {
         this.names.filter(name => name.checked = false);
    },
    methods: {
        selectAll() {
          this.names.filter(name => name.checked = true);
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Names</th>
      </tr>
      
      <tr v-for="name in names">
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="name.checked">{{name.name}}        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  
   <button @click="selectAll()">
        Select all names
   </a>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

[Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). Initialize `checked` in your data object so Vue can make it reactive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `checked` in each element of your `data.names` array so that Vue knows that it exists. The below code should perform the intended behaviour correctly:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        names: [ 
            { "name": "one", checked: false },
            { "name": "two", checked: false },
            { "name": "three", checked: false }
        ]
    },
    created() {
         this.names.filter(name => name.checked = false);
    },
    methods: {
        selectAll() {
            this.names.filter(name => name.checked = true);
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Names</th>
      </tr>
      
      <tr v-for="name in names">
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="name.checked">{{name.name}}        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  
   <button @click="selectAll()">
        Select all names
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but I get the names through an ajax call so how do I set the checked property correctly on the name object?

Comment: Then add `checked` to the results of the ajax call before assigning it to `names`.

Answer (score 1):

As Roy said, Vue has a problem with adding new properties to existing objects, however you can work around this like so:

```
created () {
    this.names = this.names.map(name => Object.assign({}, name, { checked: false }));
}
```

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        names: [ 
            { "name": "one" },
            { "name": "two" },
            { "name": "three" }
        ]
    },
    created() {
        this.names = this.names.map(name => Object.assign({}, name, { checked: false }));
    },
    methods: {
        selectAll() {
         this.names.filter(name => name.checked = true);
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Names</th>
    </tr>
      
    <tr v-for="name in names">
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="name.checked">{{name.name}}        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <button @click="selectAll()">
    Select all names
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll just throw in this variation, since from comments ***'I get the names through an ajax call'***

You can use a combination of `Vue.set()` and `vm.$data` to dynamically add to the names array after an ajax call returns.

Ref: [Vue.set(target, key, value)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

> Set a property on an object. If the object is reactive, ensure the property is created as a reactive property and trigger view updates. This is primarily used to get around the limitation that Vue cannot detect property additions.

This doc says that `target` can't be the root data object of the instance, however `Vue.set(vm.$data, 'names',...` does work.

However, in case there is some unseen consequence `names` can be moved down a level.

```js
console.clear()
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      data: {
        names: []
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      // setTimeout to simulate an ajax call
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(vm.$data)
        Vue.set(vm.$data.data, 'names', [ 
          {name: 'one', checked: false}, 
          {name: 'two', checked: false} 
        ]);
      }, 100);
    },
    methods: {
        selectAll() {
            this.data.names.filter(name => name.checked = true);
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Names</th>
    </tr>
      
    <tr v-for="name in data.names">
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="name.checked">{{name.name}}        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <button @click="selectAll()">
    Select all names
  </button>
</div>
```